# Git pre-commit hook is not running on Windows

Tags: windows, git, version-control, githooks

I'm just starting to look into Git hooks, but I can't seem to get them to run.

I set up a local repository, so there is now a '.git' directory in my project folder. I have added a '.cmd' file into the C:/path/to/my/project/.git/hooks directory named 'pre-commit.cmd'. Here is the contents of this file:

```
echo "HOOK RUNNING"
echo. 2>C:/path/to/my/project/.git/hooks/EmptyFile.txt
```

This should echo the text "HOOK RUNNING" and create an empty text file in that directory. However, if I commit changes through my IDE ([NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans)) or use [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) to commit, neither of them seem to run my pre-commit hook, as no file is created.

My understanding is that all you have to do to get a hook to run is add an executable with the name of the hook (as I have done). Am I doing something wrong?

Note: This is on a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Related (the subject of some of the answers): *[Why is my Git pre-commit hook not executable by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598639/)*

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Name your hook `pre-commit` (without any file extension).

And add `#!/bin/sh` on the first line or `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried that and now it comes up with an error when I try to commit: "error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: no such file or directory".

Comment: edited to add a 2nd suggestion (found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697210/msysgit-error-with-hooks-git-error-cannot-spawn-git-hooks-post-commit-no-su ). if this is not that, I cannot help more, I'm not really familiar with windows shell problem

Comment: That was it! You're second suggestion has made it work. Not sure why it can't just be a normal windows '.bat' or '.cmd' file...

Comment: the answer to that question is probably in git documentation

Comment: Try `chmod +x pre-commit`

Comment: I had to use  `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` to get this running under Windows.

Comment: which windows version ?

Comment: @vaughan: Thanks for the `chmod` idea. It totally failed to cross my mind. :)

Comment: @Asenar yeah, but this is the first result when searching "git pre-commit hook not running", regardless of platform

Comment: @vaughan you made my day!

Answer (score 39):

You probably don't have the permissions to run the `pre-commit` file

Run in your terminal:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Thanks to @vaughan for giving the idea

Comment: also a valid reason for why a hook would not run :D, true in my case, thx

Comment: This was driving me crazy and fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @DaneMacaulay Can you please tell me where to write this ?

Comment: Indeed, it wasn't clear in my answer, you need to run it in your terminal, I edited my answer

Comment: tried with the *chmod +x pre-commit* but it gives *chmod: cannot access '.git/hooks/pre-commit': No such file or directory*.

Comment: You need to go to the directory where your project is before running that command

Comment: After running the given command, and `ls -ls` afterwards I see this as rights on the pre-commit file: `-rw-r--r--` Doesn't seem to have execution rights yet. In a test repo I just created, the files do have `-rwxr-xr-x` rights... Odd...

Comment: chmod +x? On Windows? The question was "not running on WINDOWS".

Answer (score 24):

### TL;DR

Git hooks **work** on Git for Windows by default assuming the Git hook **script is simple**.

### Background of Git and Windows

**Please Note**: [Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_description) was made for shell [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language); thus, using Git hooks on a Windows command prompt or Windows-made PowerShell will inherently have its flaws, and complete [interoperability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability) is not to be expected.

*Using Git hooks on Windows is possible, but it has many drawbacks.*

[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) uses a shell emulator that makes Bash and shell commands possible. This means that when a Git hook is activated by Git, the Windows version will run the command using the shell emulator. Which in turn, will convert those shell commands to commands that the Windows operating system can understand. Meaning, simple shell scripts will work right off the bat. For example, the Git hook `pre-commit` that ships with an initialization of a Git repository can be run without any modification.

### Example of default behavior

1. Initialize a Git repository with the command `git init`
2. Navigate to the Git hooks directory with the command `cd .git\hooks`
3. This directory holds all the Git hook scripts. Create a file named `pre-commit`. Note:

   > The name of the file is important
4. Replace the contents with the following shell script

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "Hello, World!"
   ```
5. Navigate back to your root directory of the project and create a file named `test.txt` using the command `echo "something" > text.txt`
6. Stage the file to commit using the command `git add test.txt`
7. Commit the change and watch the pre-commit hook activate using the command `git commit -m "test commit"`
8. Verify the output to look like the following

   ```
   git commit -m "test commit"
   Hello, World!
   [master f00ccea] test commit
   ```

### Example of bad behavior

When using a very advanced shell script to do things in Git hooks, Windows shell interpretation doesn't always stack up. For example, when using the Husky Git hook plugin for NPM, along with the [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) formatter, the commands do not map 1-1. Meaning that your pre-commit Git hook will fail on Windows.

### Answering [user1578653's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609816/git-pre-commit-hook-is-not-running-on-windows)

A Git hook is an executable script; however, you are using a command prompt script (`.cmd`) and not a shell script (`.sh`). If you would like this behavior you described on a Windows operating system then create the file named `pre-commit` and place it in the `.git\hooks` directory (relative to the project you are working on). Then place the following content in that file.

**.git\hooks\pre-commit**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "HOOK RUNNING"
thisCausesError 2> .git/hooks/EmptyFile.txt
```

You will notice that the Git hook works and outputs the words `HOOK RUNNING` to the console, and the `thisCauseError` will print an error message to standard error that will be printed to the file `EmptyFile.txt`.

Comment: Indeed, even in a `git bash`, many commands in `pre-commit.sample`, created by default, do not work on my Windows installation. So I had to simplify it alot.

Answer (score 19):

In my case, I had set `core.hooksPath` to the wrong directory.

Resetting it with `git config --global core.hooksPath '~/.githooks'` solved the issue :)

You can verify your hooks path using `git config --get core.hooksPath`

Comment: I had enabled hooks for Cygwin by placing them into a subdirectory `./hooks` and making them visible to git with `cd .git; ln -sf ../hooks hooks`. As a consequence, git hooks were executed in Cygwin's git but not from within Emacs `M-x shell-command` or other places using `cmdproxy` or `cmd`, including `git gui`. After finding this answer, using `git config core.hookspath hooks` fixed it by being independent of whether git was invoked from within cmd or Cygwin's bash.

Comment: Thank you so much..
I had `error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: no such file or directory`
This solution worked for me..

Comment: helped to me, in windows!

Comment: something to not here is newer versions of husky hijack the hooksPath and point it to .husky folder.  So if you're using husky run this command, verify your hookPath dir, and copy your client side hooks to the husky dir if husky kidnapped your hookPath var.

Comment: solved thanks error is gone!

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the previous solutions worked. I moved the pre-commit file from hooks to some other location, effectively deleting the file from hooks.

That worked for me :D

Comment: yes deleting the pre-commit file in the hooks directory works

Comment: This just means that you took the git hook out, and didn't fix the hook.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I tried to run a `.bat` file.

I discovered that **backslashes need to be escaped**:

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
C:\\somefolder\\somefile.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, where I did `npm install` and accidentally deleted the **.git** folder, `npm install pre-commit --save` worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solutions suggested in other answers and it didn't help to fix this problem:

> cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory

The solution, which worked for me, was to rename the file `.git/pre-commit.sample` to `.git/pre-commit` and insert the script for formatting changed files with [Prettier](https://prettier.io/). The file with the name 'pre-commit' which I have created manually must have had some problems (encoding or end-line symbols remains unclear).

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone:

I was getting the following error:

> error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No error

It turned out that in my pre-commit file I did not have 'newline' character after last exit command:

```
#!/bin/sh
# From gist at https://gist.github.com/chadmaughan/5889802

# Stash any unstaged changes
git stash -q --keep-index

# Run the tests with the Gradle wrapper
./gradlew test --daemon

# Store the last exit code in a variable
RESULT=$?

# Unstash the unstashed changes
git stash pop -q

# Return the './gradlew test' exit code
exit $RESULT
# << must have a newline after the above command >>
```

I was running a [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) project on Windows and Gradle commands in the [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) shell and *cmd*.

Comment: Very unfortunately, many systems silently (and automatically) removes a 'newline' character at the very end of files, even if it is not an empty line (example: the [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) IDE). At the same time, many compilers can not handle a missing newline at the very end of a file. A workaround is to put some sort of comment at the very end of the file.