# Git pre-commit hook "No error" error message

Tags: git, hook, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a pre-commit hook that when I run returns this error:

`error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No error`

I have a `#!/bin/sh` at the top and have definitely used `chmod +x` on it. However, those appear to be fixes for when there is a no such file or directory error. My error simply says `No error` and I cannot work out why.

Code in the hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

changes() {
  git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AMDR --cached @~..@
}

if changes | grep -q dirname {
  echo "Test"
}
```

Comment: Can you try to target `bash` (`#!/bin/bash`) ? I'm not sure `sh` is set up as you would expect when running `git-bash` on Windows.

Comment: @LeGEC There is an `sh.exe` alongside `bash.exe` in Git for Windows, but... a `--version` on both return the same `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`. I mean `sh -c "if [[ "aa" == "aa" ]]; then echo "ok"; fi"` will work (print "`ok`"), even though `sh` is not supposed to support `[[ ... ]]` (as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42666651/6309)

Answer (score 2):

Check first, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60308153/6309), if your script does have a final newline.
Its absence would trigger a "no error" message.

Check also the eol style (end of line): LF is prefered for those bash script.

The [OP compsciman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663390/compsciman) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995735/git-pre-commit-hook-no-error-error-message/61996449#comment109679435_61996449) that switching to Git For Windows 2.26 from 2.21 solved the issue.

The only recent modification to `pre-commit` involves the removal of `git config --bool` option ([commit 81e3db4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81e3db42f3212a8e441e4ecee9a2928921cb9045#diff-d4b6e568c6ab35b16b3b54b4dd8232f8)) that I mentioned in "[How to color the Git console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439498/6309)".

Comment: I put a new line at the end as well as between every line just in case but still receive the same error.

Comment: @compsciman What is your version of Git and your local platform where the pre-commit hook is executed (Windows? Linux? Mac?)

Comment: Windows 10, git version 2.21.0.windows.1

Comment: @compsciman Does the issue persist with 2.26? (Git For Windows: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: @compsciman Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with some additional details.