# Cannot commit changes with intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have integrated git in Intellij. However, recently I am getting following error when I commit any file. The event log shows following error:

```
Commit failed with error
0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: test
cannot spawn .git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory
```

However, commit using git is working perfectly. Can u please tell me how can I solve this Intellij error so that I can commit using Intellij?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697210/msysgit-error-with-hooks-git-error-cannot-spawn-git-hooks-post-commit-no-su

Comment: I am using git bash. The link refers to msysgit

Answer (score 0):

I've had this when pushing to an organization account for which I am an invited team member, but not an owner of.

I went through a number of email exchanges with the folks at JetBrains.  I deleted and re-added the repo, re-initialized all my github settings, etc. Ultimately, I had inline my credentials in the github URL, which still bothers me, but did work, eg:

```
https://user:password@github.com/company/project.git/
```

If someone managed to come up with a way to make this work using the normal methods (stored credentials or auth token) I would love to know, but failing that, my URL solution above worked for me.