# Commit failed using git

Tags: git, pycharm

I get the error msg when trying to do a simple commit of 2 files from pycharm

```
06:11   Commit failed with error
                0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: pagination
                warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in static/images/kb-icon-arrow-1.svg.
                The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

git status outputs the following

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   static/images/kb-icon-arrow-1.svg
    modified:   static/images/kb-icon-arrow-2.svg

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app.yaml
    modified:   pytz/__init__.pyc
    modified:   pytz/exceptions.pyc
    modified:   pytz/tzfile.pyc
    modified:   pytz/tzinfo.pyc

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an actual error after the warning, like (since '`pagination`' is not a file being committed)

```
Creation of commit message file failed
```

That was [reported before](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207373845-Git-commit-error-Creation-of-commit-message-file-failed-) (with a commit message, or a [git hook issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41843828/6309)), and could be a bug (make sure to upgrade pycharm), but in the meantime, check if a `git commit -m "pagination"` in command line allows you to get past that particular commit.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by removing [i18n] config in .gitconfig

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because PyCharm couldn't write to my temp directory, which can happen either because the drive is full, or (in my case) was dismounted.